# Where is Monogame "while" or "for" loop

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm more or less new with C# and game dev in general,

I was looking at the Monogame framework and I was wondering where is the LOOP.

I mean, from what I know, to make a LOOP you have to make a WHILE(), a FOR() or by recursivity and I can't find any in Monogame, so where is the GAMELOOP ?

I used some game frameworks (in C++) such as : SFML, OpenGl (school project), and it appeared that all of them needed an explicit loop:

```
while(window is open) // pseudo code example
```

but not in Monogame, so where is the loop made ?

The fact is that if there is some way to make the same thing without a loop, I would like to learn about, it looks like something pretty useful.

Comment: You don't need to use `while` or `for` to make a loop, you can use windows message pump and send the same message over and over again. You can use timed operations to call specific methods once per every X miliseconds.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question a bit more. You're talking about several things. Game loop is very different from just having a loop.

Comment: I think you're looking for the Update() method that is called continually while the game is running.  is that correct?

Comment: Also, if you're new to C# and game dev in general I would not suggest to start with MonoGame. Perhaps try a full game dev engine like Unity3D first instead of a framework.

Comment: Oh and welcome to Stack Overflow Mocking Bird! Be sure to take the [tour] and take a look at [ask]! :)

Comment: The game loop is done in https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/master/MonoGame.Framework/Game.cs#L398 , it's either calling Platform.StartRunLoop or Platform.RunLoop , which again calls a platform specific function to implement the event/game loop

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I know for the Update() and Draw(), but the real question is : after the update and the draw, how do Monogame know he has to do it again without a "while" or "for" ?

Comment: @MockingBird you can edit your question to make that more clear. Anyway, Update and Draw are called by the MonoGame framework for every frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no main "loop" in MonoGame for you to use to keep your game running. The framework instead provides two methods to give you a way to keep your game logic and display refreshes up to date:

- Update() - Where the state of the game should be changed in response
  to user input and other checks
- Draw() - Where you actually draw things on screen to represent the current state of the game

These methods are called continually while your game is running, which is very similar to the main loop you might find in other gaming frameworks and languages.

Comment: Technically there is a gameloop but it's internal to the framework and you don't have direct access to it. It will call methods each time it loops and you have access to those.

Comment: @AlexPaven Yeah, I realised that just now and edited the post to make that a bit clearer